# show FormView inside a Widget in Odoo 10

Tags: javascript, widget, odoo, odoo-10, formview

Can I create a Widget which gets model name as a parameter and renders model's form view?

My expectation is like:

1. When a user clicks a menu, the models form is displayed in edit mode ('mymodule.asset_category').
2. The user then selects a category dropdown. For example 'Asset'. ('Asset' asset_category's 'related_model' field is type of 'ir.model' and it's value would be 'mymodule.asset')
3. new form which makes the user able to create new related model's ('mymodule.asset') instance is created inside the parent form.
4. The user fills asset fields and then clicks the Save button.
5. Thus 'mymodule.asset_category', 'mymodule.asset' objects are saved to the database.

I think I can achieve these using wizards by showing forms sequentially. But I want to know at least if it's achievable in this way.
I tried following way:

```
class AssetCategory(models.Model):
    _name = 'mymodule.asset_category'
    name = fields.Char(string=u'Category', required="True")

    related_model = fields.Many2one('ir.model', string=u'Related model')

class Asset(models.Model):
    _name = 'mymodule.asset'
    name = fields.Char(string=u'Asset Name', required="True")
    amount = fields.Float(string=u'Amount', digit=[12, 2])
```

XML will be like:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="asset_form_view">
            <field name="name">mymodule_asset_form</field>
            <field name="model">mymodule.asset_category</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="asset category">
                    <sheet>
                        <field name="name"></field>
                        <field name="related_model"></field>
                        <widget type="my_widget"></widget>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

And the Javascript:
'mymodule.asset' parameter will be set dynamically onchange of "related_model" dropdown.

```
var MyWidget = Widget.extend({

    start:function(){
        self = this;

        var dataset = new data.DataSet(this, 'mymodule.asset');
        var v_id;
        dataset._model.call('get_formview_id', [[0], {}]).then(function (view_id) {
                v_id = view_id
            });

        var fields_view_def;
        fields_view_def = data_manager.load_fields_view(dataset, v_id, 'form', false);

        var form_view = new FormView(self, dataset, fields_view_def, {});
        return form_view.appendTo(this.$el);
    }
});

core.form_custom_registry.add('my_widget', MyWidget);
```

My current code throws following error:

```
http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form_view.js:1239
Алдааны мөр:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'attrs' of undefined
    at Class.set_fields_view (http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form_view.js:1239:49)
    at Class.start (http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/views/form_view.js:97:31)
    at Class.prototype.<computed> [as start] (http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/framework/class.js:89:38)
    at http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/framework/widget.js:193:25
    at http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3276:89
    at fire (http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3119:58)
    at Object.add [as done] (http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3165:49)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3275:77)
    at Function.each (http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:383:58)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js:3272:56)
```

Comment: the result is like FormView inside Widget inside FormView. So Save button should be also custom one.

Answer (score 1):

As I know you are familiar with Odoo, you have heard about `hr_timesheet_sheet` module.

for your reference you can check out this module.

`hr_timesheet_sheet`:-

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/hr_timesheet_sheet/static/src/js/timesheet.js